# Call recursive function in Observable not working in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3, observable

I have one function in my app `getServerData()` which I call from home page and passing Token as param in my API calling in this function.

if Token is valid API will return data otherwise it will return unauthorised access  with token expired error at that time I am calling same function with new generated token form another API but some how recursive function calling not working in `Observable`.

Check below code for more detail :

```
/**
  * Get Search result from server.
  */
  getServerData(searchText: string): Observable<any> {

    let self = this;

    return Observable.create(function(observer) {

      self.getToken().then((token) => {
        console.log('Token : ', token);
self.httpPlugin.get(self.url + searchText, {}, {}).then((response) => {

       console.log("Response Success : " + JSON.stringify(response));
       observer.next(jsonResponse);

    }).catch(error => {

      if (error.status == 403) {
         //Call Same method Again
         self.getServerData(searchText);
      } else {
            console.log("Error : " + error);
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(error));
            observer.error(error);
          }
     });

  }).catch((error) => {
    observer.error(error);
     console.log("Error : " + error);
  })
});

}
```

While calling same function no code execution done.

Edit based on comment:

I am subscribe like below:

```
this.subscription =  this.api.getServerData(this.searchString.toUpperCase()).subscribe((response: any) => {
   console.log("back with data :-",response);
}, error => {
   console.log("InLine Error : ",error);
});
```

Not able to understand whats going wrong or Am I doing some mistake in calling function from `Observable()`.

Guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Observables are lazy by default, you need `subscribe` for them to start working

Comment: Yes I have make subscription base call in my Home page.

Comment: maybe, but you also should subscribe to the second recursive call `self.getServerData(searchText);`

Comment: Also using nested subscribe callbacks is an anti-pattern, try to rewrite it using `switchMap`, `mergeMap` operators and a single subscribe (if possible - single subscribe for entire app)

Comment: I am not much familiar with singleSubscrib in observer or swich & mergemap also if possible can you guide me on this how can I utilize it in my api calling scenario ?

Comment: I have added my subscribe code that I i am calling this function please check it and guide me if I am doing any mistake in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of research I found solution of my issue.

**1st** thing was I need to update my `rxjx` library as my installed version of `rxjx` was **5.5.2** so I upgraded it to latest one **5.5.11**.

**2nd** thing was I am calling Observable without `subscribe()` to that `Observable` so it will never return so I updated my recursive call from error block from where I call its `subscriber()` like below.

```
getSearchData(){
    this.subscription = this.api.getServerData(this.searchString.toUpperCase()).subscribe((response: any) => {
         console.log("back with data :-",response);
    }, error => {
         if (response.status == 403) {
            this.getSearchData();
         }else{
            console.log("InLine Error : ",response);
            this.showAlert('Error', 'Something went wrong. please try again.');
         }
    });
}
```

By doing above 2 things I am able to solve my issue.

Thanks all for your quick reply on my issue.

Hope this will help someone who is facing same issue like me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use promise in observable. Use Obserable.fromPromise and also use mergeMap. What will happen if you will use. Whenever any error will come Observable will throw error and you will able to catch. I will suggest to use Subject rather than creating your own observable and also remember one thing that don't subscribe in your service.
Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and will keep in mind above but can you just add some code for reference what you are suggesting as its going flat without code reference. It would be very helpful for me and other with code reference answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: create a demo on stackblitz then I can edit and will provide you code for the same